# Do these $L^p$ type statistics characterize distributions?

Tags: pr.probability

Define for real valued random variable $X\in L^p$, the $p$-statistic

$$X_p:=\arg\min_{c\in \mathbb R}E[|X-c|^p].$$

For example $X_1$ is the median of $X$, $X_2$ is the mean of $X$ and also $X_\infty$ is the midpoint of the range of $X$.

Let $X,Y\in L^\infty$ be two real valued random variables so that $X_p=Y_p$ for all $p>0$. Then is it true that $X=Y$ in distribution? What if we assume some regularity on $X,Y$?

This seems like an analogue to moment characterization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it looks like many different sufficiently symmetric distributions with enough concentration at $0$ will have $\arg\min_c E[|X-c|^p] = 0$ for all $p > 0$.

Concrete family of examples: if
$$ X = \begin{cases} 0  &  \text{w.prob $2/3$}  \\
                     t  &  \text{w.prob $1/6$}  \\
                     -t &  \text{w.prob $1/6$} , \end{cases} $$
then, regardless of our choice of $t > 0$, for all $p > 0$ we have $0 = \arg\min_c E[|X-c|^p]$. We can also replace $2/3$ with anything greater than $1/2$.

Proof sketch: by symmetry and monotonicity, we can suppose $0 \leq c \leq t$ in the minimization.
\begin{align}
 E[|X-c|^p] &= \frac{1}{6} (t + c)^p + \frac{2}{3} c^p + \frac{1}{6} (t-c)^p .
\end{align}
For all $p \geq 1$, this expression is strictly increasing in $c$, implying it is minimized at $c=0$.

For all $0 < p < 1$, the expression is concave in $c$ (the second derivative is negative), so it is minimized at one of the endpoints, and $c=0$ results in a value of $\frac{1}{3}t^p$, while $c=t$ results in a larger value of at least $\frac{2}{3}t^p$.